# Values of a set in a model found by Z3

Tags: java, z3, smt

I have a similar question to the one here : [How to print a Z3 Set object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15935051/how-to-print-a-z3-set-object) 
from which I couldn't figure how to print the values of a set in a model. I have one enumeration sort (code in Java):

- EnumSort rSort = ctx.mkEnumSort(ctx.mkSymbol("res"),  ctx.mkSymbol("res1"));

from which I create a set sort:

- SetSort rSet = ctx.mkSetSort(rSort)

By using this set sort, I create a Z3 constant rID and define a simple membership expression:

- BoolExpr c1 = (BoolExpr)ctx.mkSetMembership(rSort.getConsts()[0], rID);

When c1 is satisfiable, I would like to see one possible value for rID in the model. If I try with a const interpretation (i.e. m.getConstInterp(e) where e is a FuncDecl from the model), I get : "Non-zero arity functions and arrays have FunctionInterpretations as a model. Use FuncInterp.".

When I try with func interpretation (i.e. m.getFuncInterp(e)), I get "Argument was not an array constant". Am I doing something wrong here? Isn't it possible to print the values of set object? Alternatively, is there a better way of representing a variable that may contain multiple values from a sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sets are internally represented by arrays, which in turn have functions as models. getConstInterp fails, because `rID` is of set-type (internally array-type) and it throws an according exception. From the example it's not clear what `e` is, but here is an example of how to get at the FuncInterp for rID:

```
Context ctx = new Context(cfg);

EnumSort rSort = ctx.mkEnumSort(ctx.mkSymbol("res"), ctx.mkSymbol("res1"));
SetSort rSet = ctx.mkSetSort(rSort);
Expr rID = ctx.mkConst("rID", rSet);
BoolExpr c1 = (BoolExpr)ctx.mkSetMembership(rSort.getConsts()[0], rID);

Solver s = ctx.mkSolver();
s.add(c1);
Status status = s.check();
Model m = s.getModel();

System.out.println(status);
System.out.println("Model = " + m);

FuncInterp fi = m.getFuncInterp(rID.getFuncDecl());
System.out.println("fi="+ fi);
```

Note that the call to `getFuncInterp` gets the FuncDecl of the constant rID, which may be the source of the confusion.

Comment: That works, thanks! I realized that if I set the solver explicitly to QF_LIA I get that error. I haven't given a thorough thought about why but I assume set variables don't work in LIA.

Comment: Another question related to handling sets, is there an implementation of cardinality constraints on sets? Here (https://github.com/psuter/bapa-z3) I see that there is a Scala implementation but I am not sure if there is any in the other implementations of Z3.